# Returning an HTTPResponse as image in Bottle

Tags: python, bottle, google-street-view

I have just begun using the bottle framework and am trying to return an image from a certain Google street view url.

```
from bottle import run, route, redirect, request, HTTPResponse
import requests

@route('/getimage')
def getimage():
    string = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location=Cleveland, Ohio'
    req = requests.get(string, stream=True)
    text = req.text
    resp = HTTPResponse(body=text,status=400)
    resp.set_header('content_type', 'image/jpeg')
    return resp

run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

I don't understand why this is not working - I am attempting to create an HTTPResponse whose body is the text encoding of the image at the given URL; then I am setting the content-type to a jpeg so that it will return as a jpeg, but all I am getting is a message saying that the image cannot be displayed because it has errors. I have tried it on both Firefox and Chrome, and it is not working.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `r.content`, not `r.text`.

From the [requests docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content):

> You can also access the response body as bytes, for non-text requests:
>
> ```
> > r.content
> b'[{"repository":{"open_issues":0,"url":"https://github.com/...
> ```
>
> For example, to create an image from binary data returned by a
>   request, you can use the following code:
>
> ```
> from PIL import Image
> from StringIO import StringIO
> i = Image.open(StringIO(r.content))
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Just tested this..

Seems like something is wrong with the link, no image is found when navigating directly to:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location=43.20192,-83.959129

Comment: Sorry, that was just a small mistake on my part

Comment: Is there any bottle debug when navigating to the /getimage page? could you give us the traceback if there is one?

Comment: Hey, sorry - I substituted another location for the one I was working with; it doesn't work even when the string is valid, say, location=Cleveland,Ohio (I just edited it above). The traceback only says
    ResourceWarning: unclosed<ssl.SSLSocket fd=712,family=AddressFamily.AF_INET,type=SocketType.SOCK_STREAM,proto=0,laddr=<'5.38.23.188',51037>,raddr=<'155.192.64.23',421'>>
    rv=callback(*a,**ka)